# How to use svg images on button in MD (md-icon)

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have tried this form and it does not work:

```
<button md-icon-button color="primary">
  <md-icon md-svg-src="./assets/img/sprites.svg">menu</md-icon>
</button>
```

and this:

```
<md-icon svgSrc="./assets/img/sprites.svg">menu</md-icon>
```

How can i put svg images on the buttons.

---

**Update:**

I'm looking at this,

```
<button md-icon-button color="primary">
<img src="./assets/img/sprites.svg" style="max-width:25%"/>
</button>
```

but I do not know if it will be the right way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somewhere in your code inject the MdIconRegistry:

```
import { MdIconRegistry } from '@angular/material';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(
    private mdIconRegistry: MdIconRegistry,
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
...
```

later on register your svgs (ngOnInit() is a good place):

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.mdIconRegistry.addSvgIconInNamespace('img', 'sprites',
        this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('/assets/img/sprites.svg'));
}
```

Then in your component you can use your svg:

```
<md-icon svgIcon="img:sprites" color="primary"></md-icon>
```

Comment: You're right, i've cut too much imports. Edited to add DomSanitizer